# How do I add a submodule to my existing repo, make changes locally, and push all changes to my github?

Tags: git, github

Right now, I can add a submodule. Make changes, add and commit. However, I cannot push. It gives me the error.

Here's what I do:

`git submodule add --branch v1.0 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-package`

I run a simple shell script within the submodule

```
cd substrate-package
./substrate-package-rename.sh substratekitties myName
```

Then simple add, commit, push

```
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git push
```

I get the error after trying to push

```
remote: Permission to substrate-developer-hub/substrate-package.git denied to hkane729.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-package/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What can I do to make local changes, so my submodule as well as my main git repo are up to date and I can push to Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a contributor of [`substrate-developer-hub/substrate-package`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-package/graphs/contributors) in order to be able to push back to that repository.

If you need to make modifications, you should:

- [fork that repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo)
- add the fork as a submodule
- make changes in it, add, commit and push: the push will work, since it is your own repository.
- [make a PR (Pull Request)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests) to the original forked repository if you want your changes integrated back.